# Change Mac wallpaper through AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, wallpaper

I'm trying to specify a jpg file to be the wallpaper for a particular desktop, but it doesn't seem to work... It instead changes the background **into another image** in a completely different folder... anyone know how to fix it?

```
tell application "System Events"
tell current desktop
    set picture to "/Downloads/yosemite-5796x3531-5k-4k-wallpaper-el-capitan-forest-osx-apple-3962.jpg"
end tell
```

end tell

Answer (score 3):

Tested on high sierra, replace the path with any path you like

```
tell application "System Events" to set picture of (reference to current desktop) to "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Sierra 2.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2):

The path you're passing as an argument is incorrect. There is no `/Downloads` folder at the root level of the hard disk. What you probably mean is something like:

```
"/Users/yourusernamehere/Downloads/example.jpg"
```